# Maximo anywhere lookup Filtering

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am working in Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2 - WorkExecution.

I wanted to filter the logtype lookup based on based on work order tybe and device type.

Let's say if workorder type is 'AAA', device type is Meter , then I have to show the Meter related logtype, if device type is Modem, Then I have to show the Modem realted logtype.

Currently I can able to filter the logtype based on only workorder type. When it is coming to one more level filtering (Device type) I'm not able to do this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add both filters to the filter.  Take a look at ActualToolObject.js search for ".filter" and you'll see an example of how to filter on multiple fields.

```
addlLabor.filter("laborcode == $1 && orgid = $2", laborCode, currentTool.getParent().orgid)
```

Comment: We can do this kind of filter. But I wanted to do the filter like in the workOrderStatusHandler.js. Kindly help

Comment: can you please paste the code that you're trying to use that's failing?

Comment: I fixed the issue. I filtered the workOrder type using local attribute, as in statusChangeHandler.